# CKeditor 5 source editing plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor 5, and I want to install an additional plugin, 'source editing', but as far as I try, it doesn't work out for me. If I use CKEditor without
additional plugin, then everything works as it should, but when I try to register the source editing plugin, I get the following error:

[image]

My code:

```
const ClassicEditor = window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
const SourceEditing = window.SourceEditing = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing');
ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
            plugins: [SourceEditing], // <--- Trying to add a plugin to a build
            toolbar: ['sourceEditing'] // <--- Trying to add a plugin to a build
        })
        .then(editor => {
            console.log(editor);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

The versions of SourceEditing and CKEditor are the same.

[image]

Comment: What is your base editor version in package.json? and I'm assuming you are using ckeditor5 custom builder

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add the plugin to the default CKEditor.

To add it, you must download the source (see [CKEditor Online](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)) and complete the task on the source you downloaded.

After you make the change, run the npm build and check it on index.html.

At the end, import build in your project